# need to style input from a form with css in real time

Tags: forms, user-interface, text, editor, styles

Ok im struggling to find anything on this as im probably searching the wrong keywords.

I have a backed form thats use to display content on a page. When entering the details i want to be able to use a basic text editor to style the text, like bold, bullets, underline.

On top of that i would also like to allow them to wrap section in paragraph tabs, apply a certain style i.e style id="x".

Its more for backend so it doesnt have to be really user friendly but if there was an uncomplicated way of showing the styles in the form as i apply them, basically a WYSIWYG view. If not i will settle for applying the styles without having to see all the hmtl and css tags in the editor but when the information is passed via the INSERT query it will show pass all the relevant code like

My Style and so on.

Now im quite happy to spend the time learning how to do this if you point me in the right direction but i have no idea what keywords to search. Ideally if there is a script out there i can just edit to my needs would be great too rather than starting from scratch.

Finally since im learning php and mysql still keeping it dumbed down will help and also since my values im passing is going to be full of characters the code wont like what functions should i look up to pass the code and content into the database to avoid breaking the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but it seems you can achieve what you want using an editor like for example TinyMCE in combination with JQuery?
With JQuery you can show/hide items and ander your css like

```
$("p").mouseover(function () {
   $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: ok ill check that out, basically what i saying is lets say i have an article and i want 3 headers in a certain style, i want 4 items in a bullet list and i want several words bolded and italicized.

I dont want to have to type into the form 

<p><b>My Text</b></p>
<h2>My Header</h2>

Instead id rather use a text editor that does all this for me but the user entering the data just sees the bolded text and the header text rather than the coding.

When the form is submitted i want the code part inserted into the database so when i display it later in my webpage it will be styled accordingly.

Comment: TinyMCE was indeed what i was looking for